# Selecting and deleting Excel sheets with userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, worksheet

I found this code online and it does almost what I want it to. Currently it provides a list of the worksheets in a workbook (within a userform) then I can select which worksheets to delete (via checkbox)  and it keeps the un-selected worksheets.

I would like it do work opposite of that: select the sheets I want to keep and delete the unselected ones.

```
Option Explicit
'thanks domenic mrexcel mvp
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cnt As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        Cnt = 0
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                Cnt = Cnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To Cnt)
                MyArray(Cnt) = .List(i)
            End If
        Next i
        If Cnt > 0 Then
            If Worksheets.Count > UBound(MyArray) Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Worksheets(MyArray).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Call UpdateSheetList
            Else
                MsgBox "A workbook must contain at least one visible sheet.", vbExclamation
           End If
        Else
           MsgBox "Please select one or more sheets for deletion...", vbExclamation
        End If
   End With
End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
'unload form
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call UpdateSheetList
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateSheetList()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        For Each wks In Worksheets
            .AddItem wks.Name
        Next wks
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And what errors did you encounter when you tried to change the code to provide the requested behaviour?

Comment: Along with the answer provided, you will want to change the MsgBox to something like, please Uncheck the sheets you want to delete.  or something to that effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you get an answer to your question, you can accept it as an answer, letting future readers know the solution quickly without having to read all the comments.  It will also reward you and the person who answered with some reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this section of the code from True to False

```
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    'Change the next line
    If .Selected(i) = False Then
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To Cnt)
        MyArray(Cnt) = .List(i)
    End If
    Next i
```

Comment: That Worked!! thanks so much I've been stressing over this for 2 days!!